# Unpacking an php array

Tags: php

So i'm printing an array that i'm getting but i can't figure out how to access the stuff, im an complete noob by the way.

Thing i want to unpack:

[image]

code:

```
<?php
    $file = $_FILES['files'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['files']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['files']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['files']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['files']['type'];

    print_r(in_array("screenshot.jpg", $fileName)."woooo");

    print_r($file);
    $fileExt = explode(".", $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));


    $allowed = array('jpg', "jpeg", "png", "pdf");

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
        if ($fileError === 0) {
            if($fileSize < 1000000) {
                $fileNameNew =  uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;

                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);

            } else {
                echo 'You can not have a file bigger than 1 GigaByte!';
            }
        }else {
            print_r($fileError);
            echo 'There was an error uploading your file!';
        }
    }else {
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
}
```

but i do not know how to print the name that first name that im getting.

Answer (score 1):

You have a multiple file selector in your form, so all the elements of `$_FILES` are arrays, to allow for uploading multiple files. So you need to loop over them.

```
<?php
$file = $_FILES['files'];

foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $fileName) {
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
    $fileError = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
    $fileType = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];

    print_r(in_array("screenshot.jpg", $fileName)."woooo");

    print_r($file);
    $fileExt = explode(".", $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('jpg', "jpeg", "png", "pdf");

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
        if ($fileError === 0) {
            if($fileSize < 1000000) {
                $fileNameNew =  uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;

                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);

            } else {
                echo 'You can not have a file bigger than 1 GigaByte!';
            }
        }else {
            print_r($fileError);
            echo 'There was an error uploading your file!';
        }
    }else {
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
    }
}
```